# capturing words with optional prefiex

Tags: regex

I need to extend an existing regex to catch also some optional prefix.
My current regex is working fine:

```
(?:\b)(?:mon|tue|wed|thu|fri|sat|sun)(?:\b)
```

and matches any of these words separated by word boundaries. 
For instance, given the string `"mon-sun.sat"` it will match `mon`, `sun` and `sat` individually.

Now, say the words above can optionally appear prefixed by a term like `"each" "only" "any"`, for instance `"mon. any-tue or only-wed. sat. each weekend"`

I want to extend my regex to match and capture (in the example above), the terms `mon` `any tue` `only wed` `sat` but clearly not `each` because does not prefix a term of the list. In practice the pattern to capture is: optional `prefix` followed by a `day of the week`.

I have tried extending my regex in several ways but with no success. I guess I'm messing up with the word boundaries.

In other words:
There are two sets of words say `P={each,only,any}` and `W={mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat,sun}`. I need to match any element `w in W` optionally prefixed by an element `p in P`. The separators can be any \b.

EDIT:
my current attempt is
`(:?\b) ((any|only|each)?(:?\b)) (:?mon|tue|wed|thu|fri|sat|sun) (:?\b)`
but will only match `mon` `tue` `wed` `sat`.

Comment: Please share the best attempt that did not work for you. In order to explain the problem, we need to know what the problem is. Also, when saying "prefixed", do you mean there should be a hyphenated word before the alternatives listed in your original regex?

Comment: there are two sets of words say `P={each,only,any}` and `W={mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat,sun}`. I need to match any element `w in W` optionally prefixed by an element `p in P`. The separators can be any `\b`.

Comment: `\b` is a zero-width assertion, it matches no text. Use `\W*` to make sure any non-word chars are matched in between two words. Have a look at https://regex101.com/r/QOWEKL/1. And looking at your attempt, you corrupted the non-capturing groups, that you even did not need at all in the first place, `(:?)` matches an optional `:`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
\b(?:(any|only|each)\W+)?(mon|tue|wed|thu|fri|sat|sun)\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QOWEKL/6)

**Details**:

- `\b` - a leading word boundary
- `(?:(any|only|each)\W+)?` - an optional non-capturing group that matches 1 or 0 occurrences of:

  - `(any|only|each)` - a whole word (the leading word boundary has already been asserted with the `\b` above, and the trailing word boundary is assured with `\W+`) `any`, `only` each`
  - `\W+` - 1 or more non-word chars.
- `(mon|tue|wed|thu|fri|sat|sun)\b` - a whole word (due to the initial `\b` or `\W+` and a `\b` after the capturing group): either `mon`, `tue`, `wed`, `thu`, `fri`, `sat` or `sun`.

Note that `(?:...)?` non-capturing group is used to wrap an optional subpattern since it does not create any memory buffer for the capture compared to a capturing group. `?` is the quantifier making it match 1 or 0 occurrences of the subpattern sequence inside the group. `\W` is a non-word char shorthand character class that consumes any non-word char (so, any punctuation and symbols, and even whitespace will be matched).

Comment: Sorry, I left out the word boundary before `(mon`, I had it (at least in V1), but it got removed somehow. We surely need it there since the group before is optional and we need to make sure the days of the week are preceded with a word boundary. I added that word boundary back.

Comment: Put only one at the beginning : `\b(?:(any|...)\W+)?(mon...`

Comment: Now, it looks as it should.

Comment: thanks, looks fine. why my initial and final `(?:\b)` are changed in `\b`?

Comment: @giog: Yes,`(?:\b)` is equal to `\b`. `\W` does not match `_`, and if you need to match it, yes, add that to a character class, `[\W_]`.

Comment: `\W+` will match underscore which is unwanted. It needs to be `[\W_]+`

Comment: Wait, what do you need to match? What do you think `[\W_]` matches? [`\W` does not match an underscore](https://regex101.com/r/cJHB52/1) in any *regex* flavor (we are not talking about Lua patterns).

Comment: sorry my bad explanation. In Java, a word character `\w` = `[a-zA-Z_0-9]`   so `\W` will skip `_` but in my regex I need it so it's correct `[\W_]+`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143804/discussion-between-giog-and-wiktor-stribizew).